# PHP: how to access cookie set in the same request

Tags: php, cookies

During a request, I'm setting some cookies using `setcookie()` and need to access these values during the same request. Since cookies are sent to the browser as part of the HTTP header, I don't think it's available for me in `$_COOKIE` during this same request.

Is there a way to access this value other than by just having it in an accessible variable somewhere in the request?

Comment: It's not possible. You would have to write wrapper functions for setting and accessing cookies to get a similar effect.

Comment: @Aloso, good to know. I just opted to leverage the registry that the framework I'm using has.